# OpenGL Send a projectile in the direction which the player is facing

Tags: opengl

I have the players x,y,z,direction values. Now I want to translate another model in the direction the player is facing, but I don't know how to do that.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(proj.getCoordx(), proj.getCoordy(), proj.getCoordz());
    glRotatef(90, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotatef(GRAUS(GRAUS(proj.getDir()), 0, 1, 0);
    glScalef(SCALE_BATMAN + 0.005, SCALE_BATMAN + 0.005, SCALE_BATMAN + 0.005);
    mdlviewer_display(obsModel[JANELA_NAVIGATE][6]);
glPopMatrix();
proj.setCoordx(proj.getCoordx() + 0.1*cos(proj.getDir()));
proj.setCoordz(proj.getCoordz() + 0.1*cos(proj.getDir()));
```

proj is the projectile object. 
 The first time the method runs, the proj object has the players current position, so the projectile can come off of him. Next I want it to move in the direction the player was facing. Is there something wrong with my equation? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Your model is probably facing straight down the Y-axis (or the Z-axis). So assign a unit vector (0,1,0) and apply the same transforms to that vector that you applied to your model. Now send the projectile down that transformed vector.

Looking at your code it might be a simple typo:

```
proj.setCoordx(proj.getCoordx() - 0.1*sin(proj.getDir()));
proj.setCoordz(proj.getCoordz() + 0.1*cos(proj.getDir()));
```

Comment: Can you give an example please? I'm not very familiar with opengl... I forgot to mention, but this is in 3D.

Comment: I provided an edit, I think you just have a typo. If this still looks wrong try switching the cos with the sin or try changing the signs.

Comment: Yeah, there was a typo, but it's still not sending the projectile in the direction the player is facing :/

Comment: what direction is it sending it?

Comment: depends of the direction in which the model is facing. For example, the beginning X and Z of the model is -6 and -9, respectively. When I press the button with the equation you put, it sends the projectile to the right of the model